# How to manipulate tuple stored values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a tuple, In this tuple, I have two values first-one is a dictionary and the second is list.
so I want all values in the dictionary only.

I have:

```
data_tuple = ({'student':['raaj','rohan','rahul'],'teacher':['teacher1','teacher2']},[3,2])
```

But the correct output I needed:

```
data_dictionary = {'student':[('raaj','rohan','rahul'),(3)],'teacher':[('teacher1','teacher2'),(2)]}
```

Comment: Please, post your attempt.

Comment: data_tuple[0] is your answer

Comment: How do you know which key to pair with which item from the list? The dictionary has no inherent order.

Comment: Are you sure about the datatypes of your output ?
data_dictionary = {'student':[('raaj','rohan','rahul'),(3)],'teacher':[('teacher1','teacher2'),(2)]}

Comment: @Simplecode yes its a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

This might help you

Assumes that len of data_tuple[1] == length of data_tuple [0] or else you need to handle that.

```
data_tuple = ({'student':['raaj','rohan','rahul'],'teacher':['teacher1','teacher2']},[3,2])
keys = data_tuple[0].keys()
count = 0
ans = {}
for i in keys:
   ans[i] = [ tuple(data_tuple[0][i]), (data_tuple[1][count])]
   count = count+1
print(ans)
```

Output

```
{'student': [('raaj', 'rohan', 'rahul'), 3], 'teacher': [('teacher1', 'teacher2'), 2]}
```

Or else change the following if you want other output as follows

```
for i in keys:
    ans[i] = [ tuple(data_tuple[0][i]), (data_tuple[1][count], )]
    count=count+1
```

Output

```
{'student': [('raaj', 'rohan', 'rahul'), (3,)], 'teacher': [('teacher1', 'teacher2'), (2,)]}
```

Though I have same question - How do you know which key to pair with which item from the list? The dictionary has no inherent order.